# Restart kafka connect sink and source connectors to read from beginning

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I have searched quite a lot on this but there doesn't seems to be a good guide around this.

From what I have searched there are a few things to consider:

- Resetting Sink Connector internal topics (status, config and offset).
- Source Connector offsets implementation is implementation specific.

Question: Is there even a need to reset these topics?

- Deleting the consumer group.
- Restarting the connector with a different name (this is also an option) but it doesn't seems to be the right thing to do.
- Resetting consumer group to `--reset-offsets` to `--to-earliest`
- Using the REST API (Does the it provides the functionality to reset and read from beginning)

What would be the best way to restart both a sink and a source connector to read from beginning?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Source Connector:

- Standalone mode: remove offset file (`/tmp/connect.offsets`) or change connector name.
- Distributed mode: change name of the connector.

Sink Connector (both modes) one of the following methods:

- Change name.
- Reset offset for the Consumer group. Name of the group is same as Connector name.

To reset offset you have to first delete connector, reset offset (`./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server :9092 --group connectorName --reset-offsets --to-earliest --execute --topic topicName`), add same configuration one more time

You can check following question: [Reset the JDBC Kafka Connector to start pulling rows from the beginning of time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004305/reset-the-jdbc-kafka-connector-to-start-pulling-rows-from-the-beginning-of-time)

Comment: Consumer group`connect-<connectorName>` worked for me when resetting offsets for sink consumer

Answer (score 5):

**Source connector Distributed mode** - has another option which is producing a new message to the offset topic. 
For example I use jdbc source connector:
When looking on the offset topic I see the following:

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181/kafka11-staging --topic kc-staging--offsets --from-beginning --property print.key=true

["referrer-family-jdbc-source",{"query":"query"}]   {"incrementing":100}
```

Now in order to reset this I just produce another message with incrementing:0

For example: [how to produce from shell with key from here](http://bigdatums.net/2017/05/21/send-key-value-messages-kafka-console-producer/)

```
./kafka-console-producer.sh \
  --broker-list `hostname`:9092 \
  --topic kc-staging--offsets \
  --property "parse.key=true" \
  --property "key.separator=|"
["referrer-family-jdbc-source",{"query":"query"}]|{"incrementing":0}
```

Please note that you need to do the following:

- Delete the connector.
- Produce a message with the relevant offset as I described above.
- Create the connector again.

Comment: Also possible just delete the value for a specific key, see more: https://rmoff.net/2019/08/15/reset-kafka-connect-source-connector-offsets/

Answer (score 1):

With version 3.6.0, Kafka Connect will add native support for resetting the offsets of both sink and source connectors via the REST API as part of [KIP-875](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-875%3A+First-class+offsets+support+in+Kafka+Connect).

If you are running version 3.6.0 or later, first issue a PUT request to the `/connectors/{name}/stop` endpoint to stop (but not delete) the connector, then reset its offsets by issuing a DELETE request to the `/connectors/{name}/offsets` endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

a bit late but found another way. Just set the offset.storage.file.name in standalone mode to dev/null:

```
#worker.properties    
offset.storage.file.filename=/dev/null

#cmdline
connect-standalone /data/config/worker.properties /data/config/connector.properties
```